# Cascaded D-FF with Async Clocks Output Trouble

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, clock, flipflop, mixed-signal

I am trying to latch the output of a D-FF_1 into D-FF_2. When I apply a rising edge to the clock input of D-FF_2, and the output state of D-FF_2 changes, the output of D-FF_1 freezes, and gets "stuck" at a value.

Below is an example of this behavior. The output of D-FF_1 is supposed to be toggling constantly. When I apply a 0.5 Hz square wave to D-FF_2 clock, the output of D-FF_1 is affected. I am not sure why this is the case. It also only happens when the state of D-FF_2 changes.

[image]

Here is the schematic of my circuit. The clk signal is a 1kHz, 90% duty cycle square wave, and V_button is currently getting driven by a 0.5Hz square wave. Decoupling is done on pin 1 and pin 14 of the IC (2x 2.2uF caps near each pin).

[image]

Here is the layout. It is much tighter than I'd like, but I can not use the bottom layer for anything expect ground, and space is very limited. I probed the 5V pins and didn't see any glitching during D-FF transitions. The layout is my guess about why something is going wrong, but I am not sure what/how this is causing the circuit's operational problems. Another guess I had was that because the clocks aren't synchronized, there is some metastability going on. But I am not sure how the would affect the output of D-FF_1. Any insight is appreciated.

[image]

For reference, here is the D-FF pinout:

[image]

D-FF Part:

https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=26&gotoUrl=https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74hct74

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/SN74HCT74NSR?qs=SL3LIuy2dWzWupsuqUu7xg%3D%3D

Comment: While this may not be the cause of your troubles, 2uF decoupling capacitors will not be very good at suppressing fast transients. There should be a ceramic 10nF (or at most 100nF) capacitor across the supply of each IC, which will take much better care of those sudden switching currents.

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of R29?

Comment: @SimonFitch I disagree about the capacitors sizing, the capacitance value isn't as important as the loop inductance, which is kept fairly small, and the fact that this is a fairly low speed design (1kHz fundamental, ~10-100ns rise times). Also, there are no transients seen at the power pin input. I used R29 as an ad-hoc jumper, the 1k value was because I used a resistor that size elsewhere in the design. I can try replacing with a 0 ohm though.

Comment: if you've seen no suspicious transients, then I concede my suggestion is a long shot. I don't disagree with you about the loop inductance, but I disagree that small fast caps are not necessary, even at 1kHz.